# Conditional statement to check Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two environments on my rails app: development and production.

I would like to add a conditional statement to a specific controller to check which environment the app is running in order to behave differently.

How can I do this? many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Rails.env`

```
Rails.env.development?

Rails.env.production?
```

This will return boolean value `true` or `false`